# How to set browser compatibility in edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Their is a legacy web application which is working on  IE browser. But not working in edge, chrome and other browsers. How to add compatibility view setting likes IE Brower ? So that it will allow to open the application in edge browser also.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

> But not working in edge, chrome and other browsers. How to add compatibility view setting likes IE Brower ?

In this case, I suggest you to use Edge IE mode, just follow these steps:

1. Open Edge and navigate to `edge://settings/defaultBrowser`.
2. Change the value of option `Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode` to `Allow`.
3. Add the web url of your application in `Internet Explorer mode pages` list.

But this method can only work for 30 days, you need to re-add the site when this setting expires. Or you can configure IE mode sites via Group Policy, just refer to this doc: [Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies).